# Spring Integration TCP "Null payload from connection" warning

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

I have a simple TcpOutboundGateway configured via annotations with the following configuration:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="toTcpChannel")
public TcpOutboundGateway outboundClient() {
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientFactory());
    tcpOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(true);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setReplyChannel(filterChannelInput());
    tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(tcpRequestTimeout);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setRemoteTimeout(tcpReplyTimeout);
    return tcpOutboundGateway;
}

@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory() {

    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(tcpHost, Integer.parseInt(tcpPort));          
    factory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
    factory.setSoReceiveBufferSize(tcpBufferSizeReal);
    factory.setSoSendBufferSize(tcpBufferSizeReal);
    factory.setSerializer(serializer());
    factory.setDeserializer(serializer());      
    factory.setSingleUse(false);    
    return factory;
}
```

Setting `factory.setSingleUse(false);` I have detected the following random issue in my connection:

```
13:02:10,851 WARN  [org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper] (pool-6-thread-1) Null payload from connection XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX:9100:52940:22539566-1e50-4f68-a599-0b211ab3c6ef
13:02:10,851 WARN  [org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper] (pool-6-thread-1) Null payload from connection XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX:9100:52940:22539566-1e50-4f68-a599-0b211ab3c6ef
13:02:10,851 WARN  [org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper] (pool-6-thread-1) Null payload from connection XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX:9100:52940:22539566-1e50-4f68-a599-0b211ab3c6ef
13:02:10,851 WARN  [org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper] (pool-6-thread-1) Null payload from connection XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX:9100:52940:22539566-1e50-4f68-a599-0b211ab3c6ef
.....
[Stackoverflow exception in JBOSS]
```

Ok, I changed `factory.setSingleUse(true);` to close the socket for each connection and obviously set the log level to `ERROR` but I do not understand the issue. ¿What is the reason? ¿Invalid END OF MESSAGE? ¿Serializer?

Additionally, I tested with Wireshark if the socket receives null messages but there are no messages after the last received message (correctly formatted).

¿Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show your `serializer()` bean.

It means your `deserialize()` method returned `null` which is ignored (and logged).

If the deserializer detects a socket close between messages, it should throw a `SoftEndOfStreamException` which is a signal to the framework that we are done with receiving messages from this socket.

Comment: Ok, now I see the problem. I have to detect the end of the message with the string "</end>" but I did not implemented the serializer correctly. I only see examples with bytes but what about ByteArrayOutputStream examples for large streams? The AbstractPooledBufferByteArraySerializer serializers could be a good starting point?

Comment: The upcoming 5.0 has a new [`ByteArrayElasticRawDeserializer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/serializer/ByteArrayElasticRawDeserializer.java#L27). But it uses the Socket EOF to detect end of message. We should probably enhance the others to use a BAOS.